# Is there any example for audio recording using Audio-recorder

Tags: android, audio, alsa, audiorecord

is any example for audio record using Audio-recorder...and if it is possible to develop assertions function for play the audio as tracks.

Comment: Is this of any use to you? http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i am pretty sure that there are a lot of tutorials. I can provide you with ma source code. Simple&ready to use as it is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;

public class AudioRecorder {

  final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
  final String path;

  /**
   * Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of SD card).
   */
  public AudioRecorder(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);
  }

  private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
      path += ".3gp";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }

  /**
   * Starts a new recording.
   */
  public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
  }

  /**
   * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
   */
  public void stop() throws IOException {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Markiz..but my problem is while i am recording,if i hold on pause then i making resume..the concept is, now i am playing the player plays both files continuously without any delay...

Comment: this is a code copy of [benmccann.com-sandroid-audio-recording-tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/). The original article contain more than 150 comments that discusses possible problems and their solution.